# Parse a certain value ie current temperature from a website using RUBY

Tags: ruby, parsing, html

I have to parse only the 'current temperature' value in a webpage and display it. Kindly help me out please.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend you using Nokogiri. [Here's a good overview](http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/getting-started-with-nokogiri/).

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'open-uri'

data =''
open("http://some.site/page/address") do |f| // adjust URI here
  data << f.read while !f.eof?
end
temp = data[/current temperature: [0-9]+/]   // and regex here
p temp
```